# Загрузка сцены LoadLevel изменяет свет по какой-то причине

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть сцена с игрой "змейкой".

Вот она: 
[image: Вот она]

[image: Вот она]

Есть сцена с главным меню.

Вот оно:

[image: вот оно]

Если я запускаю игру через кнопку "Play" (из меню *Unity*), то в начале загружается меню (из первой сцены), а при клике в этом меню "play" - запускается непосредственно игровая сцена (Game). Почему-то эта сцена значительно темнее, нежели если запускать просто сцену игры отдельно, без меню.

Пример 1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример 2:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Скрипт MainMenu:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour {

    public string startLevel;

    public void NewGame()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel (startLevel);
    }

    public void Quit()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Game Exited");
        Application.Quit ();
    }

}
```

Что я делаю не так? Хочу узнать почему у меня идёт такое различие "цветовой палитры" и как сделать, чтобы было как на оригинальных первых двух скринах?

---

[ссылка на проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lo777z2c8ld5e57/Snake3D.rar?dl=0)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, если сбилдить игру, то можно заметить, что всё функционирует исправно. Так что волноваться по поводу этой проблемы для скомпилированной игры - не стоит.

Так что проблема только непосредственно в эдиторе.

Честно говоря сам я не знаю откуда ноги растут у этой проблемы, но, тем не менее, чтобы пофиксить это непосредственно в `Editor`'е нужно на сцене игры выбрать последовать по пути в меню:

`Window` → `Lighting` → `Lightmaps` → убрать галочку `Continuous Baking` → нажать `Build`, чтобы "приготовить" свет вручную.

Возможно у поздних версий Юнити вместо `Continuous Baking` будет `Auto` и можно даже остаться на вкладке `Scene` вместо `Lightmaps`, т.е. путь будет таким:

`Window` → `Lighting` → вкладка `Scene` → внизу видим `Auto`  → снимаем галочку  → нажимаем `Build`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Примечание**: если вы добавите еще свет или сделаете изменения, то скорее всего нужно будет опять переприготовить свет. Просто держите это в голове на всякий случай.

Comment: Это пресловутое запекание света?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer запекание теней) но что-то типа того. Почему так происходит только сказать не могу. возможно баг.

Comment: Да, я хотел сказать запекание теней. =D